# Role of yylval in lex and yacc

Tags: c, parsing, grammar, yacc, lex

I see a lot of examples where some pass the yytext to yylval while others do not.
Here is a code for a simple adder in lex and yacc

```
/* add.l */
digit [0-9]
%%
{digit}+ {sscanf(yytext, "%d", &yylval);
return(INT);
}
\+ return(PLUS);
\n return(NL);
. ;
%%
int yywrap() { return 1; }
```

and

```
/* add.y */
/* L = {INT PLUS INT NL} */
%token INT PLUS NL
%%
add: INT PLUS INT NL { printf("%d\n", $1 + $3);}
%%
#include "lex.yy.c"
yyerror(char *s) { printf("%s\n", s); }
main() {
 return yyparse();
}
```

I see no code like printf(yylval) etc. Why the code `sscanf(yytext, "%d", &yylval)` exist here. Is yylval used here somehow,what happens if we don't add that line? When do we need to include such a line in lex?

Answer (score 7):

The `yylval` global variable is used to pass the semantic value associated with a token from the lexer to the parser.  The semantic values of symbols are accessed in yacc actions as `$1`, `$2`, etc and are set for non-terminals by assigning to `$$`.  Terminals come from the lexer which needs some way of communicating the semantic value to the parser.  In a reentrant scanner, `yylval` generally becomes a reference argument to `yylex` rather than a global variable, but otherwise serves the same purpose.

In your specific example, the token `INT` has a semantic value which is the value of the integer read.  Since there are no `%type`/`%union` declarations in the yacc code, the semantic values just get default `int` type, which is just fine for holding an integer value.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Token-Values.html) (recommended reading) :

> In an ordinary (nonreentrant) parser, the semantic value of the token
>   must be stored into the global variable yylval. When you are using
>   just one data type for semantic values, yylval has that type.

Which means, values associated with a token are stored in that particular variable.

Comment: @borakur: it's used to pass the semantic value of a token from the lexer to the parser.